# NameError: name 'setBranchCourse' is not defined

Tags: python-3.x

Am calling a function in another function but it keeps telling me that function isn't defined, I have tried my best and read several online still not getting it.

This is the first function, inside this, i want to use "setBranchCourse(request)" in another function which that tells me not defined

```
@isLogin
def TESTstartcapturing(request):
      global r1,r2
      print ("come1")
      setBranchCourse(request)
      print ("come2")
      r1,r2=getr1r2(request)
      print (r1,r2)
      return HttpResponse("done")
```

This is where am using the "setBranchCourse(request)". Please any way i could get this right?
complete code now.

```
ef=None
def startcapturing(request):
      global ef
      print ("startcapturing function start")
      if setBranchCourse(request):
          ipwebcamurl=request.POST.get('ipwebcamurl')
          if ipwebcamurl:
                print ("web cam ip set",ipwebcamurl)
                request.session['ipwebcamurl']=ipwebcamurl
          print ("branch course set")
          ef=eigenfaces(request)
          if ef:
            print ("Training eigenfaces object done")
            return HttpResponse("done")
          else:
              print ("ef not created ef=",ef)
              return HttpResponse(status=410)
      else:
          return HttpResponse("failed")
```

Comment: Can you show your complete code? At least in the code that you show, `setBranchCourse` is indeed not defined.

Comment: @elethan please i have added the complete code.

Comment: OK, your code still doesn't show where `setBranchCourse` is _defined_ i.e., the source code for the function itself. Your code only shows where `setBranchCourse` is _used_. In order for you to use that function in your code you will have to a) define it (`def setBranchCourse:...`) or import it `from somewhere import setBranchCourse`

Comment: got it now thanks a lot i appreciate it works now.